# Multiline Graphs using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a multiline graph having 10 lines corresponding to each client and value as labels(Y axis) and Round as X axis... .... What is the best way to achieve this... I am reading the data from csv file using read_csv and using pyplots to get the results... Can anyone assist me in this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64kU2.png)

I tried plotting with pyplots but the results are wrong.... I am expecting 10 line graphs corresponding to each client. The value at each line graph at a certain round if under the labels column.
For eg. For 0th Round the client 0 has label 0.....
X axis round, Y axis unique values in all the labels columns

Comment: If your real data is what you sent in the picture, I think the plot you want is useless. because in axis Y you have 3 values (-1, 0, 1), and in axis X you have (1-> 5), and ten lines oscillated between  3 values.

Comment: Thanks for your details... But i want to observe the trend

Answer (score 1):

try this script. It may work or at least give a basic idea:)

Check this question too.

[Plotting multiple line graphs in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937689/plotting-multiple-line-graphs-in-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
all_labels = [
    [0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1,  0],
    [0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0,  1],
    [1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1,  1],
    [-1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1,  0],
    [1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1,  -1]
]

clients2labels = [[ round[client_no] for round in all_labels ]for client_no in range(len(all_labels[0]))]

x = [i for i in range(len(all_labels))]
for labels in clients2labels:
    plt.plot(x, labels)

plt.xlabel("Round")
plt.ylabel("Labels")
plt.title('Clients')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `read_csv` from pandas? If so, you can plot directly from pandas using `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv') 
# If you just want everything on one plot:
df.plot()

# However, typically we want a little more control over our plots
# Creating an ax object so we have a little more control over everything
# Here is if you want each line on a single figure 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
columns = df.columns 
for col in columns:
    df[col].plot(ax = ax)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
```

If you want multiple figures on the same canvas, the changes are minimal but you may find this page helpful: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

And for the plotting options for pandas, you may find this page helpful as well: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html